# Good way to use table alias in Update statement?

Tags: sql-server

Using SqlServer, and trying to update rows from within the same table. I want to use a table alias for readability.
This is the way I am doing it at the moment:

```
UPDATE ra 
SET ra.ItemValue = rb.ItemValue
FROM dbo.Rates ra, dbo.Rates rb
WHERE ra.ResourceID = rb.ResourceID
AND ra.PriceSched = 't8'
AND rb.PriceSched = 't9'
```

Are there easier / better ways?

Comment: I like to use the optional keyword "AS" (FROM dbo.Rates AS ra) for readability.

Comment: I'd use proper ANSI JOIN syntax `FROM dbo.Rates ra INNER JOIN dbo.Rates rb ON ra.ResourceID = rb.ResourceID` - it's the standard, it's clearer, and it avoids any unwanted cartesian products by forgetting the JOIN condition(s) in your WHERE clause....

Comment: marc_s has a good point; I have edited the SQL to use clearer JOIN syntax

Answer (score 45):

```
UPDATE ra 
   SET ra.ItemValue = rb.ItemValue
  FROM dbo.Rates ra
 INNER JOIN dbo.Rates rb
         ON ra.ResourceID = rb.ResourceID
WHERE ra.PriceSched = 't8'
  AND rb.PriceSched = 't9';
```

This might help in improving performance.

Answer (score 1):

**Table alias in Update Query in T-SQL( Microsoft SQL) .
for MS SQL Server 2008 R2 it's work just fine**

```
UPDATE A_GeneralLedger  set ScheduleId=g.ScheduleId
from A_GeneralLedger l inner join A_AcGroup g on g.ACGroupID=l.AccountGroupID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :

```
UPDATE ra 
SET ra.ItemValue = rb.ItemValue
FROM dbo.Rates ra, dbo.Rates rb
WHERE ra.ResourceID = rb.ResourceID
AND ra.PriceSched = 't8'
AND rb.PriceSched = 't9'
```