# Update statement not compiling using alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This is my update statement which is not being compiled:

```
Update Documents d
        Set 
            DocumentDate = 1,
            LastStatusChangedDateTime = (
                Select Top 1 DATEADD(ss,1,StatusChangedDateTime)
                    From [dbo].[DocumentStatusesHistory] dsh
                        Where dsh.DocumentID = d.DocumentID
            )
            Where DocumentID In
            (
                Select Data From dbo.Split(@DocumentIDs,',')
            )
```

I am unable to use d as an alias. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551/good-way-to-use-table-alias-in-update-statement

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
    Update Documents 
        Set 
            DocumentDate = 1,
            LastStatusChangedDateTime = (
                Select Top 1 DATEADD(ss,1,StatusChangedDateTime)
                    From [dbo].[DocumentStatusesHistory] dsh
                        Where dsh.DocumentID = d.DocumentID
            )
        From Documents d
            Where DocumentID In
            (
                Select Data From dbo.Split(@DocumentIDs,',')
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `FROM` clause:

```
Update d
Set 
DocumentDate = 1,
LastStatusChangedDateTime = (
                Select Top 1 DATEADD(ss,1,StatusChangedDateTime)
                    From [dbo].[DocumentStatusesHistory] dsh
                        Where dsh.DocumentID = d.DocumentID
)
FROM Documents AS d
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
UPDATE  d
SET     d.DocumentDate = 1 ,
        d.LastStatusChangedDateTime = ( SELECT TOP 1
                                            DATEADD(ss, 1,
                                                    StatusChangedDateTime)
                                        FROM    [dbo].[DocumentStatusesHistory] dsh
                                        WHERE   dsh.DocumentID = d.DocumentID
                                  )
```

FROM    Documents d
   WHERE   d.DocumentID IN ( SELECT    Data
                          FROM      dbo.Split(@DocumentIDs, ',') )