# SQL - Update a field if all in group are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server 2014 temp table #SourceTable that looks like this below, where AllTheSamePerDOI is a bit field, defaulted to 0:

```
ID  | DOI | Affiliations | SameAffiliationsPerDOI
----+-----+--------------+-----------------------
1   | 1   | Text A       | 0
2   | 1   | Text A       | 0
3   | 7   | Text CCC     | 0
4   | 7   | Text CR      | 0
5   | 7   | Text CCC     | 0
6   | 9   | Text CCC     | 0
```

What I would like to do is set the SameAffiliationsPerDOI field to a 1 only if all the records within the same DOI have the exact same text in all of their Affiations within that grouping.  So the final result will look like this where DOI 1 and DOI 9 both have a 1 set since everything within each of those DOIs all has the same value in Affiliations for all their records.  How Can I write a SQL statement to do this?

```
ID  | DOI | Affiliations | SameAffiliationsPerDOI
----+-----+--------------+-----------------------
1   | 1   | Text A       | 1
2   | 1   | Text A       | 1
3   | 7   | Text CCC     | 0
4   | 7   | Text CR      | 0
5   | 7   | Text CCC     | 0
6   | 9   | Text CCC     | 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to approach these problems using updatable CTEs and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select st.*,
             min(Affiliations) over (partition by doi) as mina,
             max(Affiliations) over (partition by doi) as maxa
      from #SourceTable st
     )
update toupdate
    set SameAffiliationsPerDOI = 1
    where mina = maxa;
```

You can also write this with `not exists`:

```
update #SourceTable st
    set SameAffiliationsPerDOI = 1
    where not exists (select 1
                      from #SourceTable st2
                      where st2.doi = st.doi and st2.Affiliations <> st.Affiliations
                     );
```

Which is faster probably depends on the distribution of values in the data and the indexes that are available.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your second example with the not exists, and I'm getting an "incorrect syntax near 'st'" on the first line.  I fixed that by adding a "FROM #SourceTable st" beween the SET and WHERE NOT EXISTS lines, and remove "st" on the first line.  However, I was still getting a 0 for everything.  I think I have fixed this though, but maybe there's a better way to write it?...   UPDATE S
 SET SameAffiliationsPerDOI = 1
 FROM #SourceTable S
 INNER JOIN (SELECT DOI FROM #SourceTable GROUP BY DOI HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Affiliations) > 1) AS T ON S.DOI = T.DOI

Comment: Ok, I got it working, but it's derived from your answer.  I just need to have a FROM and an alias, then use a <> instead of = since I want to update my field to a 1 only if there doesn't exist Affiliations that are different.  I've posted my final solution as the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the dense_rank() window function:

```
with ranked as (
    select DOI, dense_rank() over (partition by DOI order by Affiliations) r
    from #SourceTable),
    same as (select DOI from ranked group by DOI having max(r)=1)

update #SourceTable set SameAffiliationsPerDIO=1
where DOI in (select DOI from same)
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to update the temp table...I'm doing further processing with it later in the stored proc.

Comment: @AndyDesRosiers here's one updating in place

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE S
SET SameAffiliationsPerDOI = 1
FROM #SourceTable S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #SourceTable S2 WHERE S2.DOI = S.DOI AND S2.Affiliations <> S.Affiliations)
```

Comment: This query works great!  However, it's extremely slow for me since the Affiliations field is an VARCHAR(8000) and I can't create an index on a field this big.  I have millions of rows, and this took 7 hours to run this update statements.  It works, just slow with this crazy data model I have.

Answer (score 0):

So from my understanding, this is meant to be a one time update? Not a continuous update for similar future cases?

If that is so, then try the following bit of SQL code:

```
update #SourceTable
set SameAffiliationsPerDOI = 1
where ID in (1, 2, 6);
```

Hope that helps.

If you want it to be automated, then you may have to look into triggers.

Comment: I have posted my answer above...derived from Gordon's response.  I'm updating everything in the temp table once...but the IDs 1, 2, 6 are just sample data for my question.

Comment: @AndyDesRosiers I see. After studying your response, I'm curious to know why did you have "FROM" in your statement? I've never seen a "FROM" being used in an update statement before.

Comment: I have always used FROM in my UPDATE statements with no problem in order to use an alias on the UPDATE clause.  I'm using SQL Server 2014, and it complained in SSMS with "incorrect syntax near 'st'" on Gordon's answer.  It seems it didn't like the alias there.  This explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551/good-way-to-use-table-alias-in-update-statement

Comment: @AndyDesRosiers I see, thanks for the clarification.