# How to write UPDATE from XML with Table Alias in SQL Server 2008 already have a 'From' statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-update, sqlxml

Here I need to add an Alias name to 'TableName' AS T. The Update already have a 'From' statement for getting value from XML.

```
UPDATE TableName SET 
  TableName.PrintedBy = ISNULL(TableName.PrintedBy,der.PrintedBy), 
  TableName.PrintedDate = ISNULL(TableName.PrintedDate,GETDATE()),
  @RetVal=der.NoteId 
FROM (     
SELECT PrintedBy,NoteId
      FROM OPENXML(@hDoc1,'TableName',1)
      WITH   (  PrintedBy INT 'PrintedBy', 
                NoteId INT 'NoteId'
             )
    ) as der
WHERE TableName.NoteId = der.NoteId
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good way to use table alias in Update statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551/good-way-to-use-table-alias-in-update-statement)

Comment: @DaleBurrell It's not a duplicate. Rasanjana gave the correct answer.

Comment: His solution is specific to your query... but the actual problem is the same.

Comment: @dale Burrel but solution is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
UPDATE T SET 
T.PrintedBy = ISNULL(T.PrintedBy,der.PrintedBy), 
T.PrintedDate = ISNULL(T.PrintedDate,GETDATE()),
@RetVal=der.NoteId 
FROM (     
    SELECT PrintedBy,NoteId
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc1,'TableName',1)
    WITH   (  PrintedBy INT 'PrintedBy', 
              NoteId INT 'NoteId'
            )
     ) as der, TableName T
WHERE T.NoteId = der.NoteId
```